# Como puedo hacer un remplazo de un array?

Tags: javascript, angular

necesito hacer el reemplazo 'br' por '\r\n' cual seria la forma correcta?

```
  private createColumnHeaderExcel(){
    const celdas = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.columnasGrilla.length; index++) {
        if (!this.columnasGrilla[index]['hidden']) {
            celdas.push(this.columnasGrilla[index]);
        }
    }
    return celdas;
}
```

[image: Como se reccore el arreglo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) puedes conseguir lo que quieres:

```js
columnasGrilla = [
  {'header': 'Producto', 'field': 'producto'},
  {'header': '04<br>10<br>', 'field': 'sem_1'},
  {'header': '12<br>15<br>', 'field': 'sem_2'},
];

function createColumnHeaderExcel(){
  const celdas = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < this.columnasGrilla.length; index++) {
    if (!this.columnasGrilla[index]['hidden']) {
      this.columnasGrilla[index]['header'] = this.columnasGrilla[index]['header'].replaceAll('<br>', '\r\n');
      celdas.push(this.columnasGrilla[index]);
    }
  }
  
  return celdas;
}

console.log(createColumnHeaderExcel());
```

Con este código estarías modificando el array original. Si no quieres modficarlo, debes hacer el cambio desde variable nueva. Sería algo así:

```js
columnasGrilla = [
      {'header': 'Producto', 'field': 'producto'},
      {'header': '04<br>10<br>', 'field': 'sem_1'},
      {'header': '12<br>15<br>', 'field': 'sem_2'},
    ];

    function createColumnHeaderExcel(){
      const celdas = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < this.columnasGrilla.length; index++) {
        if (!this.columnasGrilla[index]['hidden']) {
          // Si hacemos una equivalencia directa (let data = this.columnasGrilla[index]) se cambiaría en ambos
          let data = Object.assign({}, this.columnasGrilla[index]);
          data['header'] = data['header'].replaceAll('<br>', '\r\n');
          celdas.push(data);
        }
      }
      
      return celdas;
    }

    console.log('Celdas');
    console.log(createColumnHeaderExcel());
    console.log('columnasGrilla');
    console.log(columnasGrilla);
```

Espero te pueda servir

Comment: Hola hace el reemplazo , pero no entiendo porque me cambia la forma de la tabla(solo agregue el codigo que me compartiste)

La foto de arriba es antes de presionar el botón de descarga.
[enlace](https://imgur.com/a/QEqLcrY)

Comment: El código que he puesto modifica la variable `columnasGrilla`, pasando los `<br>` por `\r\n`, que me imagino que es la variable que muestras en la tabla. Para que no ocurra esto hay que ponerlo en variable aparte. Podría ser poner en una nueva variable `this.columnasGrilla[Index]`, y a esa nueva variable hacerle el `replaceAll` y ponerla en el `push`

Comment: Si es la variable que muestra la tabla. algo es lo que te entendi:

`private createColumnHeaderExcel(){
        const celdas = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < this.columnasGrilla.length; index++) {
            if (!this.columnasGrilla[index]['hidden']) {
                let data = this.columnasGrilla[index]['header']
                 data.replaceAll('<br>', '\r\n');
                 celdas.push(data);
            }
        }
        return celdas;
    }`

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, poniendo una segunda opción donde no modifica el array original. A ver si te sirve

Answer (score 0):

Usando [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let valor = 'texto<br>1999'
console.log(valor)

valor = valor.replace('<br>', '\n\r')

console.log(valor)
```

Comment: estuve probando algo parecido pero me da error "ypeError: .replace is not a function" `private createColumnHeaderExcel(){
        const celdas = [];
        let regex = /<br>/g;
        for (let index = 0; index < this.columnasGrilla.length; index++) {
            if (!this.columnasGrilla[index]['hidden']) {
                let data = this.columnasGrilla[index].replace(regex,'\r\n')
                celdas.push(data);
            }
        }
        return celdas;
    }`

Comment: `this.columnasGrilla[index]` es un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Si conoces el índice del elemento que quieres reemplazar, bastará con realizar una simple asignación. En el siguiente ejemplo, reemplazamos el elemento 'manzana' del array 'frutas' por el elemento 'limon', sabiendo previamente que el elemento 'manzana' está en la posición con índice 2 del array:

```js
const frutas = ['naranja', 'pera', 'manzana', 'platano', 'fresa', 'granada'];
const indice = 3;

frutas[indice] = 'limon';

console.log(frutas); // ['naranja', 'pera', 'limon', 'platano', 'fresa', 'granada']
```